# How to check if the guard is working against CSRF attacks on my site?

Tags: java, web-applications, csrf, owasp

I have this project I build with maven. I want to make sure the Cross-site request forgery guard ([this link](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_CSRFGuard_Project)) is working on every page.
After the mvn clean install, the web.xml, the pom.xml, the properties file and the csrfguard.jar is present in the correct way.

How can I check if the guard is working and if it's not, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Added to pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
    <artifactId>csrfguard</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Added to web.xml:

```
<filter-name>CSRFGuard</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.owasp.csrf.CSRFGuard</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>error-page</param-name>
        <param-value>/page/error</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CSRFGuard</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<context-param>
    <param-name>Owasp.CsrfGuard.Config</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/Owasp.CsrfGuard.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>Owasp.CsrfGuard.Config.Print</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardHttpSessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

**-EDIT**

I checked for tokens in the request. No tokens were sent. What am I missing?

Comment: If you know what is a [CSRF attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) then you should be able to perform such attack on your site to test it.

Comment: Isn't there a element in the DOM that I can look for?

Comment: You can check this: [How to demonstrate a CSRF attack](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6812765/1065197)

Answer (score 0):

It says, if the token isn't present then the HTTP request will be ignored. So, you should get a browser extension that lets you see the HTTP requests. Then, copy one of the requests and omit the security token and see if it discards your request.

> When a user interacts with this HTML, CSRF prevention tokens (i.e.
>   cryptographically random synchronizer tokens) are submitted with the
>   corresponding HTTP request. It is the responsibility of OWASP
>   CSRFGuard to ensure the token is present and is valid for the current
>   HTTP request. **Any attempt to submit a request to a protected resource
>   without the correct corresponding token is viewed as a CSRF attack in
>   progress and is discarded**. Prior to discarding the request, CSRFGuard
>   can be configured to take one or more actions such as logging aspects
>   of the request and redirecting the user to a landing page.

Comment: Okay that is an answer to one of my questions. Now the more difficult one. I don't have a token in requests. What am I missing?

Comment: Check your Query String properly..

Comment: My query string is unaltered

Comment: Maybe I've looked over this, but do I have to inject something by myself in the form?