# Could post request with URL parameters be csrf hacked?

Tags: java, security, post, csrf, pci-compliance

Could post request with URL parameters be csrf hacked?

If server side has only "Consumes application/json" protection.

Using HTTPS.

If u have appropriate link, pls, share it.

Comment: Yes. It can. See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812765/how-to-demonstrate-a-csrf-attack)

Comment: Probably, no, " http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");" from your link, but in in my case server consumes application/json.

Comment: On further research, I found that this is not possible. See this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49706528/5841297) . But you can use a CSRF Token for added security.

Answer (score 0):

"Some applications will check that the Content-Type HTTP header is "application/json", so it will prevent a CSRF attack. A better security would be to use an authenticity token, this will protect HTTP requests even if the data type is not JSON."

Thx, Adithya!