# PHP and Cookies creating by my site

Tags: php

I was looking for an answer to this and didnt found, hope you can help. 
My question is this, when a user connects to the site and I Implants in his computer a cookie, whether this cookie is only valid to my site?

I mean lets say Im use a cookie with the name "user" on my site and sho user created a cookie with the name "user" by himself, can he used this cookie and tring login without passing the "login page" ?

Another question, does a user can see the name of the cookies in his computer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Basic cookie & CSRF question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750657/basic-cookie-csrf-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and yes. If you create a cookie the user can see these as they are stored on his computer. Likewise a user can easily create a cookie that mimics one from your website to bypass your login.

You can see this from the chrome developer tools:

[image: Chrome developer tools - modify cookies]

As you can see stackoverflow has a cookie called `usr` for logging us in. If you happened to know the users token you could recreate that token to bypass the login.

Comment: If I using cookie to chech if user is logged in and last seen, should I be worried about the user can see the name of the cookie that I using in my web ?

Comment: It depends on what you're storing in the cookie. If you're storing the users name, ID or password then yes. If you're using a token then no.